# Frontend - How to avoid show data from my server

Tags: angularjs, websphere

I'm creating an application using angularJS and I'm developing a simple login but there is one thing that I've notice. When the user enter a wrong password my backend returns an error code which I read and process and finally tells the user something like "wrong password", So, I was checking the response with chrome tools and my backend is showing all data from my server like:

[image]

In the content says: "WebSphere Application Server Version V8.5 Liberty...".

Maybe some hacker can check this information and search for wich are the vulnerabilites for 8.5 version of WebSphere.

My question is: How can I avoid this? or this is just a thing that backend shoud fix?

Answer (score 1):

If the concern is just with the DC.Title then you just need to start the server from the command line rather than using the eclipse tools. When launched from Eclipse a different html is output that has the DC.Title. If you launch from the command line you should just get this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

However it isn't generally a good idea to rely on the server default error page, it is better to provide something that will look right in your application/webpage. You do this by adding this to your web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <location>/my-general-error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

then you can put anything into this, including nothing.